# Link-only answer suggesting 3rd party libraries is "a high quality post"?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing the "First Posts" queue and came across a java question about fixing a `OutOfMemoryError`. The answer to review suggested two 3rd party libraries to use instead and linked only to a off-site resource (blog article) to decide which of these 3rd party library is suited better.

I flagged the answer as "not an answer", because it would better suit a comment due to the following reasons:

- It's not answering the question which was asked at all; rather than just suggesting 3rd party libraries, I would expect a explanation why this is happening and how a 3rd party library could possibly prevent this
- It's containing basically only a link to a off-site resource which could go offline anytime and makes the answer completely useless

To my surprise the "STOP! Look and Listen" came up and said: "This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting."

So, I would like to understand: Why is this considered a "high quality post" - is it purely based on the upvotes? What can I do in the future to prevent this / how to identify such answers as high-quality?

For reference, the answer this is about is:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15756196

Comment: *Bad questions generate bad answers.* Print it and paste it in your wall.

Comment: FYI, it looks like the answer was edited, then deleted and reposted, so <10k users such as myself can no longer see the original version of the post.

Comment: Surely there is a dupe for OOM in Android? It seems it's quite hard to find the dupes for Android because of the volume of bad questions every day

Comment: @Paul the Android tag *really is* that terrible a lot of the time.

Comment: @David the number of dupes on Android tag is dreadful. And the tech is changing quickly with so much junk sitting very much out of date. Yet still gaining votes...

Comment: @Constantin Luckily his first version of that answer, which was truly terrible, has been removed from history, and the updated version is actually helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> It's not answering the question which was asked at all; rather than just suggesting 3rd party libraries,

If the answer is posted because those 3rd party libraries fix the out-of-memory error the OP was asking about, then it does answer the question. Sometimes, "don't re-invent the wheel, this problem is already solved in libraries X and Y and you should use one of those" is the correct answer to the question. This is pretty normal for crypto questions, for instance. Whether this is one of those cases as well, I do not know, but if not, that would make it an incorrect answer, which should still not be flagged.

> I would expect a explanation why this is happening and how a 3rd party library could possibly prevent this

That's where I do agree it's not a very good answer in its current form. I might perhaps have left a comment asking to elaborate. Most likely though, people searching for the same problem were helped by the library suggestions and were happy with the answer even without the additional info.

> It's containing basically only a link to a off-site resource which could go offline anytime and makes the answer completely useless

No, that's not true. The answer contains information and will continue to do so even if the link stops working. (Specifically: "Try to load image using Glide or Picasso." would by itself already qualify as an answer.) The link only provides *additional* information.

---

> So, I would like to understand: Why is this considered a "high quality post" - is it purely based on the upvotes?

The determination of which posts to use for audits is automated, and yes, the fact that it got upvoted and not downvoted qualifies it. As a result of this question here, the post got downvoted, so it won't be used as an audit again in the future.

> What can I do in the future to prevent this / how to identify such answers as high-quality?

If necessary, if you suspect an audit, you can open the post outside of the queue, where you'd be able to see that the info doesn't match up with what you were presented with in the queue.